# Is it possible to aggregate the object created by PSCreateMemoryPropertyStore?

Tags: winapi, com, atl

Is it possible to aggregate the object created by `PSCreateMemoryPropertyStore`? It seems fairly straightforward to contain it, but I wasn't sure if you could aggregate it. From what I understand, in order to aggregate, you need to instantiate an object using `CoCreateInstance`, so that you can supply the `pUnkOuter` (and determine whether the object supports aggregation in the first place). That wouldn't be possible using `PSCreateMemoryPropertyStore`. But I was wondering if I am overlooking anything.  Thanks for any info.

Comment: API call arguments do not suppose aggregation, and internal implementation might be also designed to not support it. But why do you want this in first place?

Comment: Well I was interested in creating a component that essentially behaves like the memory property store, but just has some extra initialization done at the beginning.  But I guess I can accomplish it through containment.